# What is the meaning of the following?

Tags: c, arrays

```
int sampleArray[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

I understand that the `sampleArray` now points to the first element of the array.

However, what does it mean when I say `&sampleArray`? Does it mean I am getting the address of the `sampleArray` variable? Or does it mean a two-dimensional array variable?

So, can I do this:

```
int (*p)[5] = &sampleArray?
```

Comment: "I understand that the sampleArray now points to the first element of the array." This is wrong. `sampleArray` *is* an array, not a pointer; they are not the same thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, `sampleArray` does not really point to the first element of the array.  `sampleArray` *is* the array.

The confusion arises because in most places where you use `sampleArray`, it will be replaced with a pointer to the first element of the array.  "Most places" means "anywhere that it isn't the operand of the `sizeof` or unary-`&` operators".

Since `sampleArray` is the array itself, and being the operand of unary-`&` is one of the places where it maintains that personality, this means that `&sampleArray` is a pointer to the whole array.

Answer (score 7):

The name of an array evaluates to its address (which is the address of its first element), so `sampleArray` and `&sampleArray` have the same value.

They do not, however, have the same type:

- `sampleArray` has a type of `int*` (that is, a pointer-to-int)
- `&sampleArray` has a type of `int (*)[5]` (that is, a pointer to an array of five ints).

`int (*p)[5]` declares a pointer `p` to an array of five `int`s.  Ergo,

```
int (*p)[5] = &sampleArray; // well-formed :)
int (*p)[5] = sampleArray;  // not well-formed :(
```

Comment: No, sampleArray and &sampleArray have different values.  &sampleArray is the address of sampleArray.

Comment: @WhirlWind actually if you try it (not sure if it's guaranteed) they have the same value. they are of different types though.

Comment: @WhirlWind - No...sampleArray and &sampleArray have the same value. write a simple program and try this yourself.

Comment: Minor nit: the type of the expression `sampleArray` is `int [5]`, which *in most contexts* will be converted implicitly (decay) to `int *`.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, the comp.lang.c FAQ already explains this stuff:

- [So what is meant by the ``equivalence of pointers and arrays'' in C?](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html)
- [Since array references decay into pointers, if arr is an array, what's the difference between arr and &arr?](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryvsadr.html)

You probably should read [the whole section on arrays and pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Some sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  int (*p)[5] = &a; 
  //Note
  //int (*p)[5] = a; // builds (with warnings) and in this case appears to give the same result

  printf( "a = 0x%x\n" , (int *)a);
  printf( "&a = 0x%x\n", (int *)(&a));
  printf( "p = 0x%x", (int *)p);

  return;
}
```

The output - same for both ways.

```
$ ./a.exe 
a = 0x22cd10
&a = 0x22cd10
p = 0x22cd10
```

Compiler

> $ gcc --version gcc (GCC) 3.4.4
>   (cygming special, gdc 0.12, using dmd
>   0.125) Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc. This is free
>   software; see the source for copying
>   conditions.  There is NO warranty; not
>   even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS
>   FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Answer (score 0):

that is called insilization of an array. array is collection of similar type of data like int,char,float number like that.